# Need to trim a string from the end (backwards) until the second occurrence of expression

Tags: php, regex, string

I am trying to make kind of bread crumbs using PHP. (I've seen some turnkey solutions but they don't match my needs exactly)
I need to trim a string from the end (backwards) until the second occurrence of ». I've tried greedy/lazy expressions, quantifiers in different combinations but all in vain. The string either stays untrimmed or cuts up to the last(counting from the end)occurrence of » . Need your help!

This one trims up to the last occurrence:

```
<?php 
$foo = 'First Text &raquo; Second text &raquo; Third text &raquo; Maybe Forth text &raquo; ' ;
if ($thisFolder == "index"){
echo preg_replace('/(&raquo;(.+?)&raquo;)? $/', '', $foo);  
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex:

```
$parts = explode('&raquo;', $foo);
$result = implode('&raquo;', array_slice($parts, 0, -2));
```

Comment: Thanks, Casimir et Hippolyte. Your code works great for me and unlike the one with regex it doesn't remove the First Text.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to match the whole line and use the first part as `$replacement`.

```
$foo = 'First Text &raquo; Second text &raquo; Third text &raquo; Maybe Forth text &raquo; ' ;
echo preg_replace('/^(.*)(?:&raquo;.*){2}/', '$1', $foo);
```

Here, the first `.*` takes precedence, consuming as much as it can (greedy).

`$1` backreferences the part matched by the first group, used as replacement.

Comment: Thanks, Mariano. The code works just if i leave only the First Text it will be trimmed as well, but in my case it doesn't matter.

Comment: Glad it works for you. It doesn't trim if there aren't at least 2 `&raquo;` in the text... And remember regex is always slower, @casimirethippolyte's answer should be ~40% faster if that's significant to you right now, and it will trim the whole text if it doesn't have 2 separators.